# update in Eclipse with CVS recursively!

Tags: eclipse, cvs

I'm trying to run an update on my project in Eclipse with CVS.

When choosing:

```
Team -> Update
```

it executes the following command:

```
cvs update -l -d -P "/xxx/www" "/xxx/www"
```

I want the update to be recursively, so the -l option should be removed. The problem is, I don't know how. I'm using extssh and it's not possible to set any options in:

```
Team -> CVS -> Ext Connection Method
```

Where do I remove the -l option?